# How can i transform a 3d array into a voxel-file

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, computer-vision, voxel

I got a 3d array of binary data in python.
The array is in the form of [384,384,384] with 1 and 0. Real boolean values would be possible too.
How would i transform this array into a file so that i can save it and inspect it later.
Fileformats like .gox, .kvx or .vox would be wonderfull. However, any file format which will make my data visible is fine too.
Thanks.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/simple-3dviz/ In the "Quick Start" part, they have a code snippet for visualizing voxel grids. It might be helpful.

Comment: i got it too run but with my array size it was too allocate 30 TBit of Ram. Since i have a Array of [384,384,384] the module wants too double the size for various reasons which is just too big then.

Comment: Oh you didn't mention the size is a problem. If the innards are not important to you, you might need to turn your voxel representation into some 3D mesh grid (only contain triangoles on the surface) or inspect the voxels in a slice-wise manner. Or, use something like the pcl library to visualize it as a point cloud.

Comment: If it’s a NumPy array, try `np.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good open-source python package for that https://github.com/gromgull/py-vox-io.
To get started you may use this command:

```
pip install py-vox-io
```

then clone the rep and run some of the examples in the `examples/` directory.

Comment: Library seems unmaintained? I was not able to read vox files created with current MagicaVoxel program. Though writing files *probably* still works, not tested.